# how to access a variable outside the loop

Tags: java

Hi I am writing a program with some crazy logic and I have several loops. I need to access the variable 'Sets' outside my first loop. How can I do that?

```
class Example1 {
    public static String sets = new String();

    static Set<String> reports(){
        try{
            String sets = "";
            fir(i=1; i<3; i++){
                While(bufferedReader.readLine() != null){
                    if (condition1){
                        if(condition2){
                            for(condition3){
                                if(condition4){
                                    sets = ("test1" + "test2");
                                    for(condition5){
                                        sets = sets.concat("test3");
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // ****** I need to access sets here *******
}
```

Comment: Use a global variable or modularise you code and parse it as a parameter.

Comment: Declare the variable before the try or in the class. -1 for terrible code formatting. Please fix this so I can remove my down-vote.

Comment: Indentation fixed. Please understand that indentation is there so that you and anyone else can easily understand code, can easily see what code code belongs in -- something that is key in understanding this specific problem.

Comment: If you don't have a bunch of elses, use `&&` instead of a pile of nested ifs.

Comment: Thanks. I will keep this in mind next time.

Comment: @chuppu you should be using your IDE to format your code all the time, not just next time.

Answer (score 3):

You need to define the variables you want to use at the level you want to use them. e.g. if you want to access them at the outer most level of you method you need to define them at the output most level of your method, e.g. at the start of the method.

BTW: I suggest you use the formatter in your IDE to ensure your code is readable. e.g.

```
class Example1 {
    static Set<String> reports() {
        Set<String> sets = new HashSet<>();
        try {
            for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (condition1) {
                        if (condition2) {
                            for (condition3) {
                                if (condition4) {
                                    sets.add("test1");
                                    sets.add("test2");
                                    for (condition5) {
                                        sets.add("test3");
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } finally {

        }
        return sets;
    }
}
```

Note: since you are just processing data, with input from a file and output of a Set, it is highly likely you should be using Java 8 streams, however it is not clear from your example exactly what you are trying to do.